# check if a list contains all the element in an array using linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of objects and I have an array of keywords. I need to check if all the elements of the array are present inside the list of objects.
The user enters the data to be searched like this

```
 pain+fever+thirst+itching
```

My code looks like:

```
    //i check if the data is present in the list
    Dim keys = str.Split("+")
    dim linqMeddata = From m In medicineDataList
                       Where m.MedicineData.Contains(key(0)) AndAlso m.MedicineData.Contains(key(1)))
                       Order By m.MedicineName Ascending
                       Select m
```

I need to know how I can check if all the elements of the array are present in the list. Currently I am hard coding the keywords; I need a dynamic solution.

Comment: What is `MedicineData`?

Comment: MedicineData an object.
medicineDataList is of the type MedicineData

Comment: What kind of object? You can use `Contains` if it's a string or a collection of strings. If it's a string you are looking for sub-strings, if it's a collection you are looking for compete matches.

Comment: my apologies..medicine data is a member of a class and it is of type string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.All`:

```
dim linqMeddata = From m In medicineDataList
                  Where keys.All(Function(k) m.MedicineData.Contains(k))
                  Order By m.MedicineName Ascending
                  Select m
```

Comment: i will not be able to use the All() function with "keys" as it is an array.

Comment: @user2617874: the array implements `IEnumerable(Of T)` and `Enumerable.All` is an extension method of `IEnumerable(Of T)`, so that works. But you need to be able to use LINQ.